# javafx 11 project, module not found- intellij

Tags: java, intellij-idea, javafx, java-11, java-module

I'm working on a JavaFX project, I started using Netbeans having no problems then switched to IntelliJ Idea where I'm having troubles.
At first, some imports like java.sql and javafx were not working, so I added a module-info.java file to the src folder where I put all the required imports, like this:

```
module blood {
    requires javafx.fxml;
    requires javafx.controls;
    requires javafx.graphics;
    requires java.sql;
    requires java.desktop;
    requires jdk.jfr;
    opens sample;
}
```

The module has the same name as the project "blood".
Now i have no errors concerning the imports but when i run my project i'm getting this:

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.2\bin\java.exe" --module-path C:\Users\USER\Downloads\javafx-sdk-11.0.2\lib --add-modules=javafx.controls,javafx.graphics,javafx.fxml --add-modules javafx.base,javafx.graphics --add-reads javafx.base=ALL-UNNAMED --add-reads javafx.graphics=ALL-UNNAMED -Djava.library.path=C:\Users\USER\Downloads\javafx-sdk-11.0.2 "-javaagent:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2019.3.4\lib\idea_rt.jar=50526:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2019.3.4\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -m blood/sample.Main
Error occurred during initialization of boot layer
java.lang.module.FindException: Module blood not found

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I also added to the VM options this line:

```
--module-path "C:\Users\USER\Downloads\javafx-sdk-11.0.2\lib" --add-modules=javafx.controls,javafx.graphics,javafx.fxml
```

What should i do?

Comment: You shouldn't really need to add vm options. Also, should your module-info export your package? https://github.com/openjfx/samples that has some intellij examples

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
--module-path C:\Users\USER\Downloads\javafx-sdk-11.0.2\lib
```

is not sufficient to load the module `blood` that you've created for your application. On the other hand, the command-line argument

```
-m blood/sample.Main
```

expects `blood` module with `sample.Main` class to run the application. That is the reason the error reads

```
java.lang.module.FindException: Module blood not found
```

So the solution to it would be adding the output folder where the module `blood` is getting build.

```
--module-path C:\Users\USER\Downloads\javafx-sdk-11.0.2\lib;<project-output-diretory>
```

---

The [openjfx-docs](https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/) section "JavaFX and IntelliJ" further has a sub-topic "Modular from IDE" which talks about the "Add VM options" to be clear about this configuration.